# Hecke's notation for fractional ideals

Tags: commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I'm confused about some of the notation appearing in Hecke's Lectures on the Theory of Algebraic Numbers, in Section 54 of Chapter 7.

Let $\mathfrak{d}$ be the different of $K$ (the inverse ideal to the dual lattice of $\mathcal{O}_{K}$); then for each $\omega \in K$ we may write $\mathfrak{d}\omega=\frac{\mathfrak{b}}{\mathfrak{a}}$ where $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ are integral ideals and $(\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b})=1$. Suppose $\mathfrak{a}=\mathfrak{a}_{1}\mathfrak{a}_{2}$, where $(\mathfrak{a}_1,\mathfrak{a}_{2})=1$. Then Hecke says that we may find auxiliary ideals $\mathfrak{c}_1$ and $\mathfrak{c_2}$ such that $\mathfrak{a}_{1}\mathfrak{c}_{1}=\alpha_{1}$ and $\mathfrak{a}_{2}\mathfrak{c}_{2}=\alpha_{2}$ are integers and $(\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{c}_1 \mathfrak{c}_2)=1$.

$\textbf{Question 1}$: The text states that $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are elements of $\mathcal{O}_K$, so the equations involving $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are shorthand for equalities of integral ideals: $\mathfrak{a}_{1}\mathfrak{c}_{1}=(\alpha_{1})$. How do we know that such a $\mathfrak{c}_1$ exists?

$\textbf{Question 2}$: Shortly afterwards, Hecke says that $\beta:=\frac{\mathfrak{b}\mathfrak{c}_1 \mathfrak{c}_2}{\mathfrak{d}}$ is an element of $k$. Why is this true?

Thanks.

Comment: For the first question, take the inverse of $\mathfrak{a}_1$, then multiply by an integer large enough that the ideal lies in the ring. Unless, your actual question is why they satisfy $(\mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{c}_1\mathfrak{c}_2)=1$, in which case, please be a little more specific.

Comment: Thanks - how do I know that the product is principal?

Comment: The idea ought to be to construct $\mathfrak{c}_1$, start with $\mathfrak{a}_1^{-1}$, which satisfies $\mathfrak{a}_1^{-1}\mathfrak{a}_1$ is principal, then kill off denominators by multiplying by an appropriate integer. I'll write an answer expanding on it.

Comment: You mean $O_K$ integers not $\Bbb{Z}$ integers.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. @jgon, isn't $\mathfrak{a}_1^{-1}\mathfrak{a}_{1}=\mathcal{O}_{K}$?

Comment: @Bryn yes, but we want $\cc_1$ to be an integral ideal, so I proposed multiplying by an integer to kill off denominators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your question 1

- Given a non-zero ideal $I$, for non-zero $b\in I$ then $(b)=IJ$, and there is such a $b\in I$ such that $(I,J)=(1)$

  Proof : one of the properties of Dedekind domains is that $I$ becomes principal $=(b\bmod I^2)$ in $R/I^2$, then $(b,I^2)=I$ and $(b)=IJ$ means $I=(IJ,I^2)=I(I,J)$ thus $(I,J)=(1)$.
- With $b_1\in \mathfrak{a}_1  (N(\mathfrak{a}))$

  then $\mathfrak{c}_1=(b_1) (\mathfrak{a}_1  (N(\mathfrak{a})))^{-1}$ is coprime with $\mathfrak{a}_1  (N(\mathfrak{a}))$ thus with $\mathfrak{a}$,
- With $b_2\in \mathfrak{a}_2  (N(\mathfrak{a}))$

  then $\mathfrak{c}_2=(b_2) (\mathfrak{a}_2  (N(\mathfrak{a})))^{-1}$ is coprime with $\mathfrak{a}_2  (N(\mathfrak{a}))$ thus with $\mathfrak{a}$,

and hence $$( \mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{c}_1\mathfrak{c}_2)=(1),\qquad \mathfrak{a}_j\mathfrak{c}_j= (b_j/N(\mathfrak{a}))$$

For your question 2 it is because $\mathfrak{b}\mathfrak{c}_1\mathfrak{c}_2$ has the same ideal class as $\mathfrak{b}\mathfrak{a}^{-1}$

Comment: If I set $K=\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{-5}]$, $\mathfrak{a}_{1}=(2,1+\sqrt{-5})$ and $\mathfrak{a}_{2}=(3,1+\sqrt{-5})$, then $N(\mathfrak{a}_1 \mathfrak{a}_2)=6$, so $b:=12 \in (6)\mathfrak{a}_1$ and $\mathfrak{a}_{1}^{-1}=(2)^{-1}\mathfrak{a}_{1}$. Then $(12)(6)^{-1}(2)^{-1}\mathfrak{a}_1=\mathfrak{a}_1$, which isn't coprime with $\mathfrak{a}_1$: can you tell me where I've gone wrong...?

Comment: You need to find a $b$ that works, many don't. Look at $b=6(1+ 3\sqrt{-5})$ it has norm $N(6)46$ so it factorizes as $(b)=(6)(2,1+\sqrt{-5})(23,u+v\sqrt{-5})$ where $(23,u+v\sqrt{-5})$ is your ideal $\mathfrak{c}_1$ @Bryn

Comment: OK, thanks. Is the first dot point of your answer about finding $b$? I can't really understand what that sentence means.

Comment: I'm just saying such a $b$ exists. Because if it didn't then we'd have $I=\bigcup_{\mathfrak{p}\supset I}\mathfrak{p}I$ which implies $(1)=\bigcup_{\mathfrak{p}\supset I}\mathfrak{p}$ which is absurd since the latter doesn't contain $1$. I'm not giving any way to find $b$

Comment: (it is $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal appearing in the factorization of $I$, it contains $I$...)

Comment: I think I see. And is the idea of multiplying $\mathfrak{a}_1$ and $\mathfrak{a}_2$ by $N(\mathfrak{a})$ purely to ensure that anything coprime with $\mathfrak{a}_1 (N(\mathfrak{a}))$ is coprime to $\mathfrak{a}$? So one could use $\mathfrak{c}_{1}=(b_1)(\mathfrak{a}_1 (N(\mathfrak{a_2})))$ (ie. $(\mathfrak{a}_1 (N(\mathfrak{a_2})))$ for J) instead?

Comment: Yes you can take your $b_1$ in $I=\mathfrak{a}_1 (N(\mathfrak{a_2})$, all you need is some $I$ in the same ideal class as $\mathfrak{a}_1 $ and contained in all the primes containing $\mathfrak{a} $

Comment: Is this recipe for constructing $b$ correct? Any ideal $I$ in a Dedekind domain is either principal or generated by two elements. If $I$ is principal, it seems to be easy, so suppose $I=(a_1, a_2)$. Pick an integer $q$ not belonging to any of the ideals occurring in the factorisation of $I$. Write $(a_1 q)=IJ_1$ and $(a_2 q)=IJ_2$ for some ideals $J_1$ and $J_2$. Then $(q)I=I(J_1, J_2)$, so $(I,J_1)=1=(I,J_2)$.

Comment: No, you want $IJ$ to be principal, so $J=(q)$ doesn't work

Comment: $J_1$ (or $J_2$) is my candidate for $J$, and $a_1 q$ is my candidate for $b$: isn't $(a_1 q)=IJ_1$ principal by construction?

Comment: If $b=a_1q$ works then $b=a_1$ works, in most cases it doesn't

Comment: How do you know that $I=\bigcup_{\mathfrak{p}\supseteq I}\mathfrak{p}I$ implies $(1)=\bigcup_{\mathfrak{p}\supseteq I}\mathfrak{p}$?

Comment: I changed the argument

Comment: That's much better - so any $b \notin I^2$ will do?

Comment: And (just for reference), I think the property of Dedekind domains $A$ that you're really using is that for a nonzero ideal $I$ of $A$, $A/I$ is a principal ideal domain

Answer (score 1):

Let $\newcommand\aa{\mathfrak{a}}\newcommand\bb{\mathfrak{b}}\newcommand\dd{\mathfrak{d}}\newcommand\cc{\mathfrak{c}} \newcommand\pp{\mathfrak{p}}\aa=\aa_1\aa_2$, with $(\aa_1,\aa_2)=1$, all integral.

Actually, I realized that I think the easiest construction of $\cc_1$, $\cc_2$ is by [Chebotarev's density theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebotarev%27s_density_theorem) (no idea if this is at all reasonable to cite at this point in the book). The argument here is that if $H_K$ is the Hilbert class field for $K$, and we identify $\newcommand\Gal{\operatorname{Gal}}\Gal(H_K/K)\simeq C_K$, with $C_K$ the ideal class group of $K$ by the Artin map (which sends a prime ideal in the group of fractional ideals to its Frobenius element). Then by Chebotarev's density theorem, there are infinitely many prime ideals $\newcommand\qq{\mathfrak{q}}\qq$ in the ideal class of the inverse of $\aa_1$. Choose a prime $\qq_1$ that doesn't divide $\aa$. Do the same for $\aa_2$. Then by definition of the ideal class group, $\qq_i\aa_i$ is principal (and integral, since both $\qq_i$ and $\aa_i$ are), and by choice of $\qq_i$, $(\aa,\qq_1\qq_2)=1$.

**Side note**

Constructing $\cc_1$ and $\cc_2$ with the strategy I was advocating in the comments (take the inverse of $\aa_i$ then multiply by a large enough $\alpha_i$ to kill denominators) is hard to do and ensure that $(\aa,\cc_1\cc_2)=1$. However, I think Chebotarev's density theorem is definitely overkill here. Unfortunately it's gotten late, so I can't come up with a better argument right now.

**Answer to question 2**

Then regardless of how you construct $\cc_1,\cc_2$, 2 follows from their definition.
We have 
$$\frac{\bb\cc_1\cc_2}{\dd} = \frac{\bb\cc_1\cc_2 \omega}{\bb/\aa} = \aa\cc_1\cc_2\omega = \alpha_1\alpha_2 \omega \in K$$

Comment: This is very helpful. I might have to hold off on accepting until I've understood it properly. Also, Hecke's book was published in 1923, while Chebotarev published his density theorem in 1926 (but proved it in his thesis in 1922)